# 2 times chord length equals supplementary arc length

Tags: geometry

This is a problem that has bugged me for a long time. It involves a diameter and a circle with radius 1. I wanted to find the point at which the distance between the point and one end of the diameter was $\frac{1}{2}$ the length of the arc connecting the point to the other end of the diameter. 
[image]
I have used a program to find the angle's approximate measure ($118.014011183903^\circ$), and the arc's approximate length ($2.05973305864452$), but would like to know a mathematical way to solve for either one of these, as each leads to the other.

Comment: @imranfat:  no, because $x$ is the length of the chord, not the arc.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I misread, looking at the place of the 2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bisect the chord you get two right triangles which show $\frac x2=\sin (\frac {\pi-\theta}2)$ and from the arc you have $2x=2 \pi \theta$.  These are two equations in two unknowns, but the mix of polynomial and trig suggests that there will not be an algebraic solution.  Your solution is quite believable because if $x$ were the arc instead of the chord it would be obvious that $\theta=\frac {2\pi} 3$ and your solution is a little smaller because the chord represents a little more angle than the arc.  I think you have done everything that there is to do.  Congratulations.

Comment: Makes sense, is my answer right you think?

Comment: Yes, I think it is.  Because $\sin y \lt y$ the angle subtended by $x$ will be a little higher than $\frac \pi 3$.  Your answer for $\theta $ is just a little smaller than $\frac {2 \pi}3$, which is consistent.  I haven't checked the numerics, but it makes sense.

Comment: @Ross Millikan How did you get "2=2?"

Comment: @JiaoCtagon:  from the arc on the upper right.  $2x$ is given and $2\pi \theta$ is the length of an arc of length $\theta$ in a unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach: In the triangle containing the $x$ you can apply the law of cosines to arrive at $x^2=2+2cos\theta$. (I also applied the identity cos(A-B)=cosAcosB+sinAsinB). The circle has radius $1$ and thus circumference $2\pi$ and thus $2x=\theta$. Now eliminating $\theta$ from those two equations ultimately gives $\theta^2$=4(2+2cos\theta$ and putting this in DESMOS confirms your angle approximation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator . There is no exact answer possible

Answer (score 1):

Consider unit radius:

$$ 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{x/2}{1} + 2 \,x = \pi$$
$$ \theta\,\text{marked on your drawing}\, = 2 \,x \, \text {radians}$$ 
$$\rightarrow \theta \approx 2.06 \text{ radians} $$.